# Get maximum value in list of filenames

Tags: r, regex, string, max

I have a list of filenames with the general title

```
a_file_name_1
a_file_name_34
a_file_name_452
new_data_2018.csv
```

I would like to rename the `new_data_2018.csv` file so that its numerical end is one greater than the largest pre-existing file in the folder.

So far I have

```
#list files in directory
list_files_names <- list.files(directory_2018)

#capture largest suffix
largest_value <-
new_largest_value <- largest_value + 1

# rename file
file.rename("new_data_2018.csv", paste0('a_file_name_', new_largest_value)
```

My question is how I can I collect the existing filenames in such a way that returns the largest suffix. I imagine that it might have something to do with regular expressions for which the following regex might be useful `[0-9]*$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse number, select the biggest one and then add +1:

```
files <- c("a_file_name_1",
"a_file_name_34",
"a_file_name_452")

largest_value <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", files))
new_largest_value <- max(largest_value) + 1
```

If you have other numbers in your files, you can use some regex or just split it on underscores and then transform the last element into numbers:

```
files <- c("a_file_name_2019_1",
"a_file_name_2019_34",
"a_file_name_2019_452")

largest_value <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", sapply(strsplit(files, "_", fixed = TRUE), tail, 1)))
new_largest_value <- max(largest_value) + 1
```

Or using regex:

```
largest_value <- as.numeric(sub(".*\\_", "", files))
new_largest_value <- max(largest_value) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there an easily accessible edit to the pattern if the file names include a related number, for example: instead of "a_file_name_1"... it was "a_file_name_2019_1" "a_file_name_2019_31", etc.?

Comment: Does that mean that you want to consider only the numbers before `.`?

Comment: the numbers at the very end of the title but after the last underscore

Comment: Thanks! It works great. In order to resolve this, I had to rename the `new_data_2018.csv` and exlude the missing value in `largest_value`. Appreciate the revision!

Answer (score 2):

Using tidyr:

```
list_file_names <- list.files(directory_2018)

new_largest_value <- max(extract_numeric(list_file_names))+1
```

Note: This is dependent on no undesired numbers being in the file name.  Example:

```
extract_numeric('file_2A3B4_name_222.csv')
```

will return: 234222

EDIT-  If you have a consistent year in your existing file names, this could work:

```
list_file_names <- list.files(directory_2018)

file_name_numbers <- extract_numeric(list_file_names)

values_no_year <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern = '2018', replacement='', x = file_name_numbers))

new_largest_value <- max(values_no_year)+1
```

Note: This could run into problems when your file numbers contained 2018.

Comment: `tidyr::extract_numeric()` is deprecated according to documentation. `readr::parse_number()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

The regex proposed by the OP `[0-9]*$` points into the right direction as it will pick zero or more digits at the very end of the string. *The crucial part* is the `$` which specifies *a match at the end of a line*. (Interestingly, the `$` has been omitted from the regex's in all other answers posted so far).

To be on the safe side, I suggest to use `[0-9]+$` which picks *one* or more digits at the very end of the string. There is *no need* [to rename files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896557/get-maximum-value-in-list-of-filenames/58095364#comment102215751_57896668) like `new_data_2018.csv` which contain a number in between but not at the very end.

So, using

```
filenames <- c("a_file_name_1", "a_file_name_34", "a_file_name_452", "a_file_name_2019_31", "new_data_2018.csv")
```

the code

```
library(magrittr) # piping used to  improve readability
largest_value <- filenames %>% 
  stringr::str_extract("\\d+$") %>% # pick numbers at the very end of filenames
  as.integer() %>% 
  max(na.rm = TRUE)
```

computes

```
largest_value
```

> ```
> [1] 452
> ```

which can be used to construct the new file name.

---

The whole process can be written as a pipe:

```
library(magrittr) # piping used to  improve readability
filenames %>% 
  stringr::str_extract("[0-9]+$") %>% # pick numbers at the very end of filenames
  as.integer() %>% 
  max(na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  add(1) %>% 
  paste0("a_file_name_", .) %>% # create new file name
  file.rename("new_data_2018.csv", .)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Specify the folder path
        string folderPath = @"C:\NumberedFiles";

        // Get the filenames in the folder
        string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);

        // Create a list to store the Numbers
        List<int> NumberList = new List<int>();

        foreach (string filename in filenames)
        {
            //Extract the number from the filename.
            //Assuming the number is between the last underscore character and the last dot before the file extension
            //(eg. a_file_name_34.txt)

            //Get index of the last underscore charater
            int IndexOfLastUnderscore = filename.LastIndexOf("_");

            //Get Length of characters between the underscore character and the dot character
            int LengthOfNumber = filename.LastIndexOf(".") - filename.LastIndexOf("_") - 1;

            //Extract the number and convert to an integer.
            //Add one to starting index of the substring.
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(filename.Substring(IndexOfLastUnderscore + 1, LengthOfNumber));

            NumberList.Add(number);
        }

        // Get the maximum number
        int MaxNumber = NumberList.Max();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add zeros to the numbers in your file names, then sort by file name in descending order.

```
a_file_name_00452
a_file_name_00034
a_file_name_00001
```

The top file name will contain the maximum value.

Comment: thanks, I would prefer something that does not have an upper bound on the number of documents I can store

Answer (score -1):

Another way would be to keep a special text file in the folder that only holds the last number used.  Then read and increment the number every time a new file is added to the folder.  This is a faster way to get the maximum value used, especially if you have thousands of files in the folder.  It's also a less complicated solution.